# Flutter Cloud Firestore - is it possible to disable network for client?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to figure out if there is a way that i can disable network for the cloud firestore on the flutter framework. I know this is possible to do for Java:
[image]
I have looked through the documentation for the packages firebase_core, cloud_firestore and firebase_auth but cant seem to find any documentation for this method. I also tried to search online but cant seem to find anything specific for Flutter when it comes to cloud_firestore.

Does anyone know if this is a possibility or a fix?

Comment: Have you looked at `Firestore.instance.settings(persistenceEnabled: false)`? it might solve your problem.

Comment: @ChennaReddy yes i am aware of this setting, and i want offline persistance to be enabled (It enables offline persistance right?) . I want to speceficly enable the user to be offline or online, so when they add a document to the cloud, it wont be uploaded before i allow them to.

Comment: Any Solution? i have the same requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation for the `Firestore` client for Flutter](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Firestore-class.html) doesn't mention any method relation to disabling the network, so it looks like that functionality wasn't wrapped in FlutterFire.

Your best bets are to [file a feature request](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues) on the repo, and possibly a PR implementing it.

Comment: Did think about doing that aswell, but wasnt sure if i had just overlooked something. thanks